# Data structure to represent a polyhedron

Tags: data-structures, computational-geometry

I need a data structure to represent a non-triangulated polyhedron and was wondering which one would be the most suitable for my case.

Here is what I need to do with it:

- For each face, obtain the neighboring faces
- Get the edge any two faces share in common
- Store the coordinates (to draw them later)

There is no need to manipulate the structure (e.g. delete edge, split faces etc).

I have considered using DCEL, but I'm afraid it could be overkill. Could anyone offer me some suggestions?

Comment: How do you obtain your geometry? (importing from a file? generation? gui?) 

What operation are going to perform on it? (rendering? exporting to a file? something else?)

Comment: @Artium I'm importing all the information from a .OBJ file, so I have a list of faces and vertices. As for the operation, I would like to build a new object with the planar net of the polyhedron and render it.

Comment: It may be that I do not understand your situation completely, but it seems to me that you can store the polyhedron in memory in a similar way it is stored in the obj file? Rendering is easy, as you already have vertices of the polygons (faces) that you need to draw in one place.

Comment: @Artium My current object stores the data in a way that is similar to the obj file and rendering is indeed very easy. But I'm trying to develop an algorithm to unfold the polyhedron according to the logic [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/237337), so I was looking for a data structure with information about the neighboring faces as well.